# Table cell view in IOS not scaled properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The cells are supposed to have a title and a small overview as shown in story board, I even tried the automatic dimension to set the height of row but it doesnt seem to work

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I programmatically changed the settings of the table view.
tableview.Rowheight = heightofmyimage

helped me to scale this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the constraints like this

```
      10                        10

                                 |
      |
                          10  - lbl - 10 /// .lines = 0

10 - img (wid = 100 ) -          |

      |                   10  -  lbl2 - 10   /// .lines = 0

                                 |

     10                         10
```

Width can be proportional , I meant to set a width anyway , also set **compressionResistancePriority** (Vertical) to lbl to 1000

Comment: I'm not sure how easy it is for people to follow your answer. Although I understand what you are saying, it took me much longer than it should have to comprehend what you mean.

Comment: @CharlieFish I don't think it's that hard , it's a visualization of constraints like the popup you set constraints with in Xcode